# Getline and EOF

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file. The file contents have a newline between words in a sentence and two newlines between sentence. I can only read one sentence. I have tried to put a EOF as a delimiter in getline but it seems not to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

The file contents are:

> County
>
> Grand
>
> Jury
>
> said   Friday   an   investigation  of   Atlanta's  recent   primary
>   election  produced   `` .  no   evidence   '' .  that   any
>   irregularities   took   place   . .   The  jury  further   said   in
>   term-end   presentments   that  the   City   Executive   Committee
>
> But what's get printed is:
>
> County
>
> Grand   Jury   said   Friday   an  investigation  of   Atlanta's
>   recent   primary   election  produced  `` . no   evidence   '' . that 
>   any   irregularities  took   place
>   . .

```
string line;
string a, b;
ifstream infile("myFile");

 while (getline(infile, line))
{
    istringstream iss(line);

    if (!(iss >> a >> b)) { break; } // error

    cout << a << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the file contents?

Comment: Can you also show us the output please?

Comment: County 
Grand 
Jury 
said 
Friday 
an 
investigation 
of Atlanta's 
recent 
primary 
election 
produced 
`` .
no 
evidence
'' .
that 
any 
irregularities 
took 
place
. .

The 
jury 
further 
said 
in

Comment: The comments section does not allow newlines. Please post it as an edit to your question.

Comment: The output: The
Fulton
County
Grand
Jury
said
Friday
an
investigation
of
Atlanta's
recent
primary
election
produced
``.
no
evidence
''.
that
any
irregularities
took
place
..

Comment: Edit your question, please. Trust us, posting the contents here doesn't work.

Comment: The `!(iss >> a >> b)` will trigger on the first line because the first line only has one string in it, "County", thus `break`ing out of the `while` loop.  So there is no output created. If you actually got output then you must have reported your input wrong, or not shown the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>,
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> >
    tokenizer;

void printPhrase(const vector<string>& _phrase) {
    if (!_phrase.empty()) {
        vector<string>::const_iterator it = _phrase.begin();
        cout << "Phrase: \"" << *it;
        for(++it; it != _phrase.end(); ++it)
            cout << "\", \"" << *it;
        cout << "\"" << endl;
    } else
       cout << "Empty phrase" << endl;
}

int main() {
    boost::char_separator<char> sep("", "\n", boost::drop_empty_tokens);
    istreambuf_iterator<char> citer(cin);
    istreambuf_iterator<char> eof;
    tokenizer tokens(citer, eof, sep);

    int eolcount = 0;
    vector<string> phrase;
    for (tokenizer::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == "\n") {
            eolcount ++;
            if (eolcount > 1 && eolcount % 2 == 0) { // phrase end
                printPhrase(phrase);
                phrase.clear();
            }
        } else {
            eolcount = 0;
            phrase.push_back(*it);
        }
    }
    if (!phrase.empty())
        printPhrase(phrase);
    return 0;
}
```

The basic idea is to keep newlines in the output, count them and if there're 2, 4, .. even number of sequential newlines print words collected so far. A non-newline token breaks the sequence, and this token is added into the accumulator.